# I cannot figure out how to exculde links from preventdefault

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, preventdefault

I want to exclude links inside a child-div from preventDefault

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#parent").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
<div id="child"><a href="mylink.html" alt="link">click me!</a></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to get the link in the child `div` working? I have spent about 3 hours looking for the answer right now, and I can't seem to figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the target that triggered the event is not the anchor.  If it is not do not propagate the event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#parent").click(function(event){
    if(!$(event.target).is("a")){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check that the original target of the event isn't an `<a>` tag:

```
$('#parent').click(function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName !== 'A') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: @PeterSpit You need to select jQuery as the framework in the top-left corner, and comment out the original `click` event handler. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wHM4y/1/

Comment: Never mind! It works on my desktop, but it still doesn't work on my mobile phone. The script I am writing is a bit more complicated then the example above ;) I think for some reason it has something to do with mobile Chrome, or with the touch-script I am using

Comment: @PeterSpit I noticed you switched the accepted answer from mine to Kevin's. Does his solve the issue with your mobile device that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').on('click', "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: He **doesn't** want to call `event.preventDefault()` if he's clicking on the `<a>` tag, so the opposite of this.